# NoMethodError (undefined method `filter_search' for #<Class:0x13e45a4a>):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From controller i'm calling model

@approvals = @approvals.filter_search(params[:_start], 10,params[:_order], params[:_sort])

class method in model

def self.filter_search(start, limit, order, sort)
   /code..../
  end

Answer (score 0):

@approvals looks to a result set from a query. It's an array (or more specifically an active record relation that extends array) and you are try wanting to run the method ActiveRecord_Relation#filter_search, which of course doesn't exist.

So it looks like you are trying to run your filter after the fact.

ActiveRecord lets you add filters to your query, something like:

```
approvals = Approval.offset(10).limit(10).order(:sort)
```

Comment: Details? Error messages? What is the approvals table's schema?

Comment: Error message: NoMethodError (undefined method `filter_search' for #<Class:0x13e45a4a>):

approvals table's schema:                                                               CREATE TABLE public.approvals
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  item_type character varying NOT NULL,
  item_id integer NOT NULL,
  event character varying NOT NULL,
  state integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  object text,
  original text,
  reason text,
  created_at timestamp without time zone,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone,
  admin_email character varying,
 
)

Comment: The error message you report: `Error message: NoMethodError (undefined method `filter_search' for #<Class:0x13e45a4a>)' in my mind says you did not try this, or did not understand how to try this. My answer does not use your filter_search, but rather chains ActiveRecord methods on the query of the model to achieve the filter. There is no :sort column in your approvals table, so that part is wrong, I was guessing what params[:_sort] was supposed to mean. So leaving that off, `Approval.offset(10).limit(10)` would return approvals starting with the 10th record, and limited to 10 records.